# Get server certificate used for current request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Kestrel server is configured with multiple endpoints with a different certificate on each one. I can find currently used cert in debugger via

```cs
var f = HttpContext.Features.Get<ITlsConnectionFeature>();
((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.TlsConnectionFeature)f)
   ._sslStream.LocalCertificate;
```

But I'm interested in reflection-free method.

Comment: Hi @OwnageIsMagic, what is your scenario? Where do you want to get such certificate, in the middleware or filter or controller?

Comment: @Rena controller, but in all those scenarios I have access to `HttpContext` (ultimately via `IHttpContextAccessor`), so I don't think it actually matters, so I would say in ASP part (not Kestrel connection middleware). I want to show certificate info to requester in some specific format that not easily reproducible via `openssl x509` cli and save myself from manual loading and wildcard matching certificates from config since it's already done by server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NET 8
Use new `context.Features.Get<ISslStreamFeature>()`.

For pre-NET 8
Add `ServerCertificateSelector` in the https options and then you can `context.Features.Get<SslStream>()`. See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46442#issuecomment-1420150725